# Optimising jQuery to avoid Safari: “This webpage is using significant energy...”

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am experiencing the Safari warning message on my webpage, but I only have a small amount of custom jQuery in use.

> This webpage is using significant energy. Closing it may improve the responsiveness of your Mac.

I have included my jQuery below, can anyone suggest if this is likely to be the cause? I can't see anything specific in it that would utilise a lot of resources and cause the warning to appear.

Can I optimise this code to reduce the impact on the user?

```html
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fa-user-o').click(function() {
      jQuery('#modalBkg').fadeIn(300);
    });
  });

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fa-times-rectangle').click(function() {
      jQuery('#modalBkg').fadeOut(300);
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fa-align-justify').click(function() {
      jQuery('.aby-sticky-menu').slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'li.vc_tta-tab a,li.vc_tta-tab,.vc_tta-panel-title', function() {
      $('html, body').stop();
    });

  });
</script>

<script>
  jQuery(".fa-times-rectangle").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(".modalBody, .modalLeft").animate({
      opacity: 0.4
    });
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(".modalBody, .modalLeft").animate({
      opacity: 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You start a new animation with each pointer movement in your `mouseover` handler, ie. 'continuously'. You also should only have _1_ `ready` handler, and why are you wrapping the definition of the `click`handler (`on` call) ? You might wish to study some introductory book on jquery, the _complete_ api docs, or a tutorial.

Comment: First question is what else is being loaded in page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is your use of `mouseover`, which fires once for *every pixel* that the mouse moves over the element the event is attached to. When combined with an animation this can be very demanding on the system. A better workaround for this would be to use `mouseenter` instead, which can be achieved with the use of [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover)

Even better than that would be to use CSS, but that would require the `.modalBody` and `.modalLeft` elements to be siblings or descendants of `.fa-times-rectangle`, which seems unlikely given the context.

Also note that you don't need multiple `script` tags, combine them in to one. Similarly, you don't need multiple document.ready event handlers, combine them in to one.

With all the above said, try this:

```html
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.fa-user-o').click(function() {
      $('#modalBkg').fadeIn(300);
    });

    $('.fa-align-justify').click(function() {
      $('.aby-sticky-menu').slideToggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'li.vc_tta-tab a, li.vc_tta-tab, .vc_tta-panel-title', function() {
      $('html, body').stop();
    });

    $(".fa-times-rectangle").click(function() {
      $('#modalBkg').fadeOut(300);
    }).hover(function() {
      $(".modalBody, .modalLeft").animate({
        opacity: 0.4
      });
    }, function() {
      $(".modalBody, .modalLeft").animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

As an aside, I would check if the call to `$('html, body').stop()` is actually doing anything, and therefore needed. It seems an odd thing to be doing as it implies you're continually animating the entire `body`, which would also cause performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information Rory, I'm pretty sure it was the use of `mouseover()` that was the primary issue; also `.stop()` is being used to disable a default scroll effect when the `.vc_tta-panel-title` container is clicked. Thanks again for your help with this issue :)